# Using generating functions find the sum $1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 +\dotsb+ n^3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I am quite new to generating functions concept and I am really finding it difficult to know how to approach problems like this. I need to find the sum of $1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 +\dotsb+ n^3$ using generating functions. How do I proceed about it?

Comment: If you have a generating function $f(x)$ for a sequence $a_n$, then $xf'(x)$ gives a generating function for $na_n$. Can you produce a generating function for $a_k = k^3$ (for $k \le n$) this way?

Comment: The other element of the puzzle: from the generating function for the sequence $a_n$, do you understand how to find the generating function for the sequence $b_n=\sum_{i\leq n}a_i$?  (Hint: if $g(x) = \sum_n b_nx^n$, what is $xg(x)$?  What is $xg(x)-g(x)$? )

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let $s_n=\sum_{k=0}^nk^3$; your generating function for these numbers will be $$f(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}s_nx^n\;.$$

You know that the sequence satisfies the recurrence $s_n=s_{n-1}+n^3$. Multiply this recurrence by $x^n$ and sum over $n\ge 0$:

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}s_nx^n=\sum_{n\ge 0}s_{n-1}x^n+\sum_{n\ge 0}n^3x^n\tag{1}\;.$$

The lefthand side of $(1)$ is $f(x)$. We assume that $s_n=0$ for all $n<0$, so we can rewrite $(1)$ as $$f(x)=x\sum_{n\ge 0}s_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\sum_{n\ge 0}n^3x^n=x\sum_{n\ge 0}s_nx^n+\sum_{n\ge 0}n^3x^n=xf(x)+\sum_{n\ge 0}n^3x^n$$ and see that $$f(x)=\frac1{1-x}\sum_{n\ge 0}n^3x^n\;.\tag{2}$$

To deal with the summation in $(2)$, start with $$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\;.$$ Differentiate and multiply by $x$ to get $$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n\ge0}nx^n\;.$$ Repeat: $$\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{n\ge0}n^2x^n\;.$$ And one more time: $$\frac{x(1+4x+x^2)}{(1-x)^4}=\sum_{n\ge 0}n^3x^n\;.$$ Thus,

$$f(x)=\frac{x+4x^2+x^3}{(1-x)^5}\;.$$ Now decompose $f$ into partial fractions:

$$f(x)=-\frac1{(1-x)^2}+\frac7{(1-x)^3}-\frac{12}{(1-x)^4}+\frac6{(1-x)^5}\;.$$

Finally, you need to know some standard generating functions. In particular, you need to know that $$\frac1{(1-x)^k}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}x^n\;.$$ With that you get finally that

$$\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(-\binom{n+1}1+7\binom{n+2}2-12\binom{n+3}3+6\binom{n+4}4\right)x^n\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac14\left(n^4+2n^3+n^2\right)x^n
\end{align*}$$

and therefore that $$s_n=\frac14\left(n^4+2n^3+n^2\right)=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right)^2\;.$$

Comment: Nice post. I believe there is a typo on the line "Thus, $f(x)=...$". The denominator should be $(1-x)^5$.

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks. You’re absolutely right.

Comment: Perhaps it would be good, to make that nice (+1) derivation easier memorizable, using the incidence, that the occuring coefficients *(1,4,1)* are Eulerian numbers and *(1,7,12,6)* are $(0! \cdot 1, 1! \cdot 7, 2!\cdot 6, 3!\cdot 1)$ and thus simple scalings of the Stirling numbers 2'nd kind. Knowing this, one can simply gain the coefficients for problem-variations, where the exponent of the initial sequence varies...

Comment: Thanks Brian for the beautiful solution. You made it absolutely clear. :)

Comment: @user1631009: You’re welcome.

Comment: I think the function should be $f(x) = \frac{x(x^2 +4x+1)}{(1-x)^4}$ and not power 5, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%28x%5E2%2B4x%2B1%29%2F%281-x%29%5E4

Wolfram even confirm this as it generates the sequence $\{1,2^3,3^3,.... \}$

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{x(x^2+4x+1)}{(1-x)^5}$ generates a different result @BrianM.Scott

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%28x%5E2%2B4x%2B1%29%2F%281-x%29%5E5

Comment: @alkabary: No, it’s correct. You’re forgetting that $f(x)$ is $\frac1{1-x}\sum_nn^3x^n$, not $\sum_nn^3x^n$.

Comment: But how come it gives incorrect results wen u do that taylor expansion of wolfram alpha (The 2nd link I provided) @BrianM.Scott

and without $\frac{1}{1-x}$ it gives the correct one (first link)

Comment: @alkabary: What do you mean? The second link shows exactly what it should show.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this more prettily with exponential generating functions. Note that
$$e^{kx} = \sum_n \frac{k^n x^n}{n!}$$
so
$$1+e^x+e^{2x} + e^{3x} + \cdots + e^{kx} = \sum_n \frac{(1+2^n+3^n + \cdots + k^n) x^n}{n!}.$$
The left hand side is 
$$(e^{kx}-1) \cdot \frac{1}{e^x-1} = \left( kx + \frac{k^2 x^2}{2} + \frac{k^3 x^3}{6} + \cdots \right) \left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{x}{12} - \frac{x^3}{720} + \cdots \right)$$
where the second factor can be expressed in terms of [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).

Now compare coefficients of $x^3$ on both sides.

Comment: could you elaborate on this a little bit? I don't fully understand how to continue from where you left off.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that $k^{3}=\frac{1}{4}[k^{2}(k+1)^{2}-(k-1)^{2}k^{2}]$, so

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{3}
=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{n}[k^{2}(k+1)^{2}-(k-1)^{2}k^{2}]
=\frac{1}{4}n^{2}(n+1)^{2}$$

Comment: Thanks Alfred. Is there any way of solving this using generating functions?

Comment: @user1631009: I'm sorry. Because the question is of discrete type, I don't know how to deal it using generating function. Why you persist on using generating functions to solve the problem?

Comment: Interesting solution, even though it is not using generating functions. I wonder if similar approaches work for higher powers?

Comment: @Maesumi: Yes, there exist similar approaches work for higher powers, but seems more complex.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude Alfred, but I don't understand why an answer that doesn't even answer the question is getting upvotes.

Comment: I agree with Graphth. This answer may be correct, but the question seems to be asked with the intent to better understand generating functions. This question does not address the question.

Comment: @Graphth: I'm sorry, I'm wrong in understand and solve the problem as claim.

Comment: @AlfredChern, Can you explain what you did here? is it a telescoping series?

Comment: This is cheating, in a way, as the terms are just $\sum_{0 \le k \le n} k^3$ and $\sum_{0 \le k \le n - 1} k^3$, and so it telescopes.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, then

$$
z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} A(z)
  = \sum_{n \ge 0} n a_n z^n
$$

and also:

$$
\frac{A(z)}{1 - z}
  = \sum_{n \ge 0} \left( \sum_{0 \le k \le n} a_k \right) z^n
$$

Starting with:

$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} z^n
  = \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$

the generating function for the sum you want is:

$\begin{align}
 \frac{z}{1 - z}
   \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z}
     \left( z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z}
       \left( z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} \frac{1}{1 - z} \right)
     \right)
  &= \frac{z (1 + 4 z + z^2)}{(1 - z)^5}
\end{align}$

Thus:

$\begin{align}
\sum_{0 \le k \le n} k^3
  &= [z^n] \frac{z (1 + 4 z + z^2)}{(1 - z)^5} \\
  &= [z^n] (z + 4 z^2 + z^3) \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{-5}{k} z^k \\
  &= [z^n] (z + 4 z^2 + z^3) \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{k + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} z^k \\
  &= \binom{n - 1 + 4}{4}
        + 4 \binom{n - 2 + 4}{4}
        + \binom{n - 3 + 4}{4} \\
  &= \frac{n^2 (n + 1)^2}{4}
\end{align}$

Note that:

$$
\sum_{0 \le k \le n} k^3
  = \left( \sum_{0 \le k \le n} k \right)^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to get blown away, consider the following, taken from Aigner's "A Course in Enumeration" (Springer, 2007). Define:

$$
s_m(n) = \sum_{0 \le k < n} k^m
$$

and it's exponential generating function:

$
  \begin{align}
    \widehat{S}_n(z)
      &= \sum_{m \ge 0} s_m(n) \frac{z^m}{m!} \\
      &= \sum_{1 \le k \le n - 1} \sum_{m \ge 0} \frac{k^m z^m}{m!} \\
      &= \sum_{1 \le k \le n - 1} \mathrm{e}^{k z} \\
      &= \frac{\mathrm{e}^{n z} - 1}{\mathrm{e}^z - 1}
  \end{align}
$

This is almost the exponential generating function for the powers:

$
  \begin{align}
    \widehat{P}(z)
      &= \sum_{m \ge 0} n^m \frac{z^m}{m!} \\
      &= \mathrm{e}^{n z}
  \end{align}
$

Sadly, the series $\mathrm{e}^z - 1$ has no reciprocal, as it has no constant term. But we can write:

$$
    (\widehat{P}(z) - 1) \widehat{B}(z)
    = z \widehat{S}(z)
$$

where:

$$
    \widehat{B}(z)
      = \frac{z}{\mathrm{e}^z - 1}
$$

whose coefficients are the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number):

$\begin{align}
    \widehat{B}(z)
      &= \sum_{n \ge 0} B_n \frac{z^n}{n!} \\
      &= 1 - \frac{1}{2} z + \frac{1}{6} \frac{z^2}{2!}
    - \frac{1}{30} \frac{z^4}{4!} + \frac{1}{42} \frac{z^6}{6!}
    - \frac{1}{30} \frac{z^8}{8!} + \frac{5}{66} \frac{z^{10}}{10!}
    - \frac{691}{2130} \frac{z^{12}}{12!}
    + \frac{7}{6} \frac{z^{14}}{14!}
    - \dotsb
\end{align}$

and finally:

$$
    \sum_{m \ge 0} s_m(n) \frac{z^{m + 1}}{m!}
      = \sum_{m \ge 0} z^m
   \sum_{0 \le k \le m}
     \binom{m}{k} \frac{(n z)^{m - k}}{(m - k)!} B_k
$$

Comparing coefficients of $z^{m + 1}$ and simplifying:

$$
    s_m(n)
      = \frac{1}{m + 1}
    \sum_{0 \le k \le m} (-1)^k \binom{m + 1}{k} B_k n^{m + 1 - k}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way is to start with:

$$
\sum_{0 \le k \le n} z^k = \frac{1 - z^{n + 1}}{1 - z}
$$

differentiate thrice:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z}
   \left( z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z}       
     \left(
       z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} \frac{1 - z^{n + 1}}{1 - z}
     \right)
   \right)
= \frac{1 + 4 z
          + z^2 
          - z^n (1 - 3 n^2 - n^3)
          - z^{n + 1} (4 - 6 n^2 - 3 n^3)
          - z^{n + 2} (1 - 3 n + 3 n^2 + 3 n^3)
          + z^{n + 3} n^3}
       {(1 - z)^4}
$$

Taking the limit as $z \to 1$ of this mess (l'Hôpital to the rescue) again gives:

$$
\sum_{0 \le k \le n} k^3 = \frac{n^2 (n + 1)^2}{4}
$$

The above courtesy of my CAS, [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net). Any transcription errors are mine only.

Answer (score 0):

This is the particular case $p=3$ , more generally known as the [Faulhaber formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Proof_with_complex_numbers) which gives a closed-form for the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n k^p$

Some more proofs can be found here: [p1](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_Formula),[p2](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Beardon201-213.pdf),[p3](https://www.emis.de/journals/AMEN/2018/AMEN-170803.pdf)